# Attribute Error on python 3x

Tags: python, tensorflow, graph, python-3.6

I am working on Object detection with tensorflow api. I take codes on githup and try to debug and I face to face that error.

```
  File "<ipython-input-10-7adfcc2a8173>", line 3, in <module>
    with detection_graph.as_defult():

AttributeError: 'Graph' object has no attribute 'as_defult'
```

No problem with my camera. I aldready installed which necessary every module

PLSS help me

thank you

Comment: as_defult must be a spelling error. Try as_default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without your code I cannot be entirely certain it is the only issue, but I think you are getting the error because of a misspelling. It should be as_default instead of as_defult. Use `detection_graph.as_default()` instead.

Comment: thank you so much how I miss that i dont know. I have some questions now it's work but have new problem here.

 ValueError: The name '<image_tensor>:<0>' looks a like a Tensor name, but is not a valid one. Tensor names must be of the form "<op_name>:<output_index>".

Comment: image_tensor = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('image_tensor:') my code is like that

Comment: @RafetTürkel You’re missing the <output_index>. Try image_tensor = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name(‘image_tensor:0’).

Comment: Umm sorry I couldnt write 0 here. İf you write mail adress I will be happy or can u take me mail ?? 
rafetturkel@gmail.com

Comment: i already do that but no solve. thank you for helping me. This is my thesis. PLS contact me

Comment: File "<ipython-input-6-a83b5c23c010>", line 10, in <module>
    image_tensor = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('image_tensor:')

  File "C:\Users\Rafet\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 3635, in get_tensor_by_name
    return self.as_graph_element(name, allow_tensor=True, allow_operation=False)

  File "C:\Users\Rafet\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 3459, in as_graph_element
    return self._as_graph_element_locked(obj, allow_tensor, allow_operation)

Comment: File "C:\Users\Rafet\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 3495, in _as_graph_element_locked
    "form \"<op_name>:<output_index>\"." % repr(name))

ValueError: The name 'image_tensor:' looks a like a Tensor name, but is not a valid one. Tensor names must be of the form "<op_name>:<output_index>".

Comment: I have this issiue with my code. pls help me as soon.